# Is there a keyboard shortcut that moves tabs left and right in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a very visual person, and I work better when I drag similar tabs together. I can do that using the cursor, but I'd love to be able to do that using the keyboard.

Ideally, there would be keyboard shortcuts to move a tab:

- to the left
- to the right
- to the further left side
- to the further right side

Basically, I'd love to be able to do in VSCode what I can do in Chrome using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rearrange-tabs/ccnnhhnmpoffieppjjkhdakcoejcpbga) extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the "Move editor left|right" command.

[image: Move editor Right]

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. By default, the following shortcuts are:

**To shift a tab to the left:**

- Windows or Linux: Press Ctrl + Shift + Page Up
- Mac: Cmd + Shift + Page Up

**To shift a tab to the right:**

- Windows or Linux: Press Ctrl + Shift + Page Down
- Mac: Cmd + Shift + Page Down